# angular 2 / selector did not match component

Tags: angular, typescript

So, I am trying to implement this toggle button in ts / angular2. Compiling doesn't render errors, but the console does:

```
ERROR Error: The selector "app-punch" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:1079)
```

**html**

```
<toggle-button [config]="config" (onStateChange)="onStateChanged($event)">
</toggle-button>

{{value | json}}
```

easy, but doesn't render due to previous error.

**component ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToggleButtonConfig } from './toggle-button.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-punch',
  templateUrl: './punch.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './punch.component.scss' ]
})
export class PunchComponent  {
  value: boolean;
  config: ToggleButtonConfig;

  constructor() {
    let self = this;

    this.config = {
      state: false,
      onText: 'true',
      offText: 'false',
      onColor: 'btn btn-primary',
      offColor: 'btn btn-danger'
    };
  }

  public onStateChanged(value: boolean) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

doesn't render any errors when compiling

**module ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { PunchComponent } from './punch.component';
import { ToggleButtonComponent } from './toggle-button.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ PunchComponent, ToggleButtonComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ PunchComponent ]
})
export class PunchModule { }
```

doesn't render any errors when compiling

**toggle-button.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'toggle-button',
    template: `<button [ngClass]="state ? onColor : offColor" (click)="onClick()">
      {{ state ? onText : offText }}
    </button>`
})
export class ToggleButtonComponent {
    @Input() state: boolean;
    @Input() onColor: string;
    @Input() onText: string;
    @Input() offColor: string;
    @Input() offText: string;
    @Input() config: ToggleButtonConfig; 
    @Output() onStateChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    public ngOnInit(): void {
      if (this.config !== null) {
        this.state = this.config.state;
        this.onColor = this.config.onColor;
        this.offColor = this.config.offColor;
        this.onText = this.config.onText;
        this.offText = this.config.offText;
      }
      if (typeof(this.state) !== 'boolean')
        this.state = false;
      if (!this.onText || this.onText === '') 
        this.onText = "Button";
      if (!this.offText || this.offText === '')
        this.offText = this.onText;
      if (!this.offColor || this.offColor === '')
        this.offColor = this.onColor;
    }

    public onClick(): void {
        this.state = !this.state;
        this.onStateChange.emit(this.state);
    }
}

export interface ToggleButtonConfig {
  state?: boolean;
  onColor: string;
  onText: string;
  offColor?: string;
  offText?: string;
}
```

doesn't render any errors when compiling. Seems that the export of the interface doesn't work as it should... but thats just a thought.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using, and are you bootstrapping your module? E.g., from `main.ts`: `if (environment.production) {enableProdMode();} platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`. If this is not the root module, then please include your usage of the component. Whatever your case, it looks like the calling context does not import `PunchModule`.

Comment: Did you add `<app-punch></app-punch>` element to your `index.html` file?

Comment: Thanks, Mike! I am using Version 6

Comment: I am bootstrapping the module. 
Not sure where I should PunchModule ...

Answer (score 0):

as you are using angular 2, so you have to use **moduleId**

here's an example,

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-punch',
  templateUrl: './punch.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './punch.component.scss' ]
})
```

sometimes we have to give the relative path to avoid name collision so we have to use the property of component annotation named “module.id” .by using this component look at the current folder path instead of from root level.

Comment: to be precise. I am using version 6 of angular (sorry). It is recommended not to use the moduleId - which I tried anyways, without success

Comment: Yes, In angular 6 you can't use moduled. I had given this answer beacuse you mentioned in title i.e. angular 2.